# Intellij debug configuration with only an external tool

Tags: debugging, maven, configuration, intellij-idea, bukkit

I am coding bukkit plugins on my Mac laptop, and to test I want to launch a jar file within the Intellij debug system (current version). If you dont know what bukkit is, all that really matters is that I am trying to execute
"java -jar craftbukkit.jar" in a certain directory.

I have figured out how to do this using a Maven configuration. Basically I created a new Maven configuration, then just ignored everything about Maven and added an external tool to the "Before Launch" section. Everything works, but there is this somewhat annoying notification whenever I close the server session. (Bukkit is the name of the configuration).

```
Error running Bukkit: No valid Maven installation found. Either set the home directory in the configuration dialog or set the M2_HOME environment variable on your system.
```

Basically I am wondering if

1. I could somehow prevent this warning from showing up as a bubble/in the event log
2. I could configure the Maven settings somehow such that it wouldnt do anything Maven related.
3. I could use another configuration method to just use the external tool I wish.

Also, for the record, I have tried setting the home directory and setting the maven directory, but while it does fix the errors, it causes the logger to try to run a maven session which quits out with another error. Basically if I try to fix the pop up the obvious way, it only leads to another error since I am not actually trying to use Maven.

Finally, you may say "its just a little balloon, who cares". True, its not a huge inconvenience, but to me it is worth at least doing some research before giving up on.

Comment: Which maven plugin / goal are you using to execute the jar? Perhaps there are other plugins available that can work differently, for example antrun plugin.

Comment: I am using java to execute the jar file "java -jar craftbukkit.jar". You probably are talking about something else though. Using any other Maven related thing would simply be a means to trick Intellij into just running the java command I want.